# convert case statement to where condition

Tags: amazon-redshift

I am trying to convert this case statement:

```
(CASE UPPER(dc.source_name) WHEN 'DART' THEN dc.ad_campaign_id ELSE dc.cfid END) AS rodeo_order_id
```

into a condition in the `where` clause.

Any help is appreciated!

Thanks,
S

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible. The Case-Expression in the Select clause decides the content of a returned column for all returned rows while the where-clause defines which rows are returned.

You have to give a better explanation what problem you have in order to get an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have to admit I don't understand need for this, but something like this might be the solution (assuming `ad_campaign_id` and `cfid` are of the same type):

```
select dc1.ad_campaign_id
from <table> dc1
where UPPER(dc.source_name) = 'DART'
UNION
select dc2.cfid
from <table> dc2
where UPPER(dc.source_name) != 'DART'
```